# Download sync magic in android app

Tags: android, download, blogs, offline, google-play

I am working on an android app for displaying certain blogs of various categorization.

I am done with the app and now recently I came across [OB Programming Interviews app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.optimized.bits&hl=en) which display various programming interview questions on the basis of algorithmic categorization.

This app contain a feature of downloading the entire question database for offline usage. I want to implement a similar functionality in my app. Can anybody suggest me something or give me a direction to proceed as after some hours of google search I am still clueless about the idea of the implementation.

Thanks in advance!